# Permanently disable Safari caches

Tags: macos, safari

I'm disabling the cache from Safari developer menu, but each time I reboot my computer, the cache is re-enabled.

I'm looking for a permanent solution for disabling the cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Empty the cache from the Develop menu.
2. Quit Safari.
3. Lock ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db from Finder's Get Info inspector.

This prevents Safari writing to the cache.

---

If you're here looking for how to disable cache now the option mentioned in the question is removed in Safari 11, see **[How to disable all caches in safari 11?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299693/how-to-disable-all-caches-in-safari-11)**

Comment: this is not working for me. Safari is still caching on the twilight zone. I have renamed all Cache.* files on the directory and created zero byte versions of them using `touch` then locked these 0 byte versions using `chmod 000`. Safari is still caching probably in memory, because the files continue to be 0 bytes.

Comment: @Space I doubt this Q&A is what you’re looking for, see the link to the question regarding Safari 11.

Comment: not working too. :(