# Safari 11 – Permanently disable cache

Tags: safari

I work at a web design firm. I need Safari's cache to be *permanently* disabled on my work computer, as it creates too much confusion when I'm testing websites. This setting should persist after I restart Safari, and when the inspector is closed.

The method in [Permanently disable Safari caches](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250247/permanently-disable-safari-caches) is no longer working as of Safari 11. I'm testing with http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The linked duplicate was given in the answer to the question you linked to. If this doesn't solve the problem either, [edit] your question to be specific about how and why.

Comment: @grgarsideThe linked duplicate only works while the inspector is open. I already stated this requirement in my question.